# Is a Tree or Autocomplete better UX for the below Scenario?

Tags: tree, autocomplete

I am creating a web app (web app only, no mobile functionality) and am wondering if I should use a tree selection (where the user drills down through hierarchical categories until they find their selection) or an autocomplete (where the desired result is typed in and gets filtered based on what has been typed and then the result can be selected. More specifically Material Angular are the versions of each I would be using. The links for the description and functionality of each are below

**Tree**

https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview#nested-tree

https://stackblitz.com/angular/eaalmyagbxpn?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-nested-overview-example.ts

**Autocomplete**

https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#adding-a-custom-filter

https://stackblitz.com/angular/yoqybbxoegl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts

**The specifics of this widget are as follows:**

The user can only choose 1 option.

Each individual user will be creating these options for their own account. So the selectable options the User 1 sees will be completely different from those that User 2 can see, since each user will create them specifically for their own needs.

I am confident that the number of options each user creates for themselves will be no less than 5 and no more that 50 the overwhelming majority of the time (there will not be restriction put in place either way but it would it would be rare for someone to go above or below these numbers).

They will probably use this function between 5 and 25 times a day

Please let me know what everyone thinks. Would a tree selection be a better UX experience or would an autocomplete be better?

Comment: If someone really is using that input that many times per day, I would highly recommend pre-filling the last used choice to save them the time navigating the tree or taking their hand off the mouse to type a few characters over and over.

Comment: I think that context here is very important to give answers. What type of entries are those?

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you to go for autocomplete. Autocomplete is better than searching for a 50th element in a tree.

No matter how much efforts you put on structuring menus user prefers to use search bar.
Here in your example **autocomplete** represents search-bar and **tree** represents menu.

Take a look at menu of below site
https://materializecss.com/helpers.html
It has autocomplete

[image]

As well as tree with depth of 1.
You can increase depth by nesting collapsibles inside collapsibles.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Tree element**

1. List of elements which has 2 to 3 level of nesting is called tree element.
2. Tree element is usually used for navigating through branches and if the list is long, it is grouped together along with a search element.

**On autocomplete**

1. Its mostly used along with form elements. To note, like "advanced search" can be used stand-alone, so is the case for auto-complete.

**Solution**

1. If you don't have **2 to 3 levels of nesting, a grouping of list element*s and the user gets to select only one option*, autocomplete should work.
2. Otherwise, go for a tree with a search.

It would have been great to see if you had attached any wireframe for the resulting page once the user selects something.